# How to check whether paid In-App purchase is working?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

1. I have a paid In-App purchase in my application.
2. I can buy paid apps using promo code that I get from the itunes connect.

How can I buy a In-App purchase like this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to iTunes Connect. You can see an option  of Manage Users. Under that option you can create test accounts for testing the in-app purchases integrated in your app. Hope that help.

[image]